# How to *reversibly* remove a column within `change_table` in a Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know I can do this in a `change` migration and have it be reversible:

```
  add_column :widgets, :color, :string
  remove_column :widgets, :flavor, :string
```

But strangely, `change_table`->`remove` does not work like this.  Instead of params `(name, type)`, it takes a list of column names.  (If you attempt to append a type parameter, it gets interpreted as a column name.)

```
  change_table(:widgets) do |t|
    t.column :color, :string
    t.remove :flavor, :string    # <-- nope! It tries to remove a column named "string"
  end
```

When you try that, you get this error:

```
  remove_columns is only reversible if given a type.
```

Is there another call I am be overlooking?  It seems weird that `change_table` could be missing such a fundamental use case, but I don't see any calls in [the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html) that can do it.

Answer (score 3):

While experimenting, I tried this and it works:

```
  change_table(:widgets) do |t|
    t.column :color, :string
    t.remove :flavor, type: :string
                     #^^^^^
  end
```

So I guess that's the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table` is generally just a thin wrapper around `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements` - in this case [remove_columns](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_columns) which takes a list of columns and an options hash.

> type and other column options can be passed to make migration reversible.
>
> ```ruby
> remove_columns(:suppliers, :qualification, :experience, type: :string, null: false)
> ```

`remove` really just provides the first argument - which is the table.

Comment: This pattern is repeated in a lot of places in Rails - for example the form builders are just wrappers around the low-level tag helpers.